# Job Activity Monitor has incorrect Next Run

Tags: reporting-services, runtime, job-scheduling

We recently moved our SSRS server to a backup, but the time on the back up was in 2014.
When we noticed this, we corrected it. But all the jobs ran, and updated the Next Run time to 2014.

So none of the scheduled jobs are working now.

I triggered some of the jobs manually through the Job Activity Monitor, and the jobs run, but the Next Run time remains in 2014.

How can I correct this? I haven't found an option of manually changing the Next Run time, and I don't really want to recreate the schedules for each refresh, emailed subscription and ETL.

Update:

I found the next_run_date field in the sysjobschedules table and updated it to 2013. But it doesn't seem to update the system. When I open and refresh the Job Activity Monitor, the dates still show 2014.

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to SQL Server Agent scheduled jobs created by Reporting Services report subscriptions? If so you need to fix the date in the ReportServer database, not in SQL Server metadata (you should NEVER be updating SQL Server metadata tables manually!).

Have a look in the "Subscriptions" and "Schedule" tables in the ReportServer database to see where the 2014 date is coming from.